# Is there cloudify's management and agent communication encryption?

Tags: cloudify

Is there cloudify's management and agent communication encryption?
if not, How can I implement encryption?

thank you very much! Steve

Answer (score 0):

The internal communications between Cloudify agents and managers is not encrypted.

In a production setting, you would have all of the Cloudify internal traffic use a dedicated management network, and application processes should use a dedicated application network.

Comment: What mechanisms can guarantee the security of transmission？ just depend on internal network?

Comment: Correct. Internal communications between agent and manager are not encrypted. The front-end REST API and web console support HTTPS setup.